Least squares fitting with bounded response variable Y in Python
I have a problem of the form:
Xb = y

where X is the design matrix of a 2D polynomial, b is the parameter vector and y is the response variable.
I'd like to find an optimum parameter vector b that minimizes the 2-norm |y - X b| while at the same time respecting a constraint on Xb, so that c1 < Xb < c2, with c1 > 0 and c2 > 0 for known c1, c2. In other words, Xb should be bounded to a positive range.
I already have a solution in place for unbounded Xb, using scipy.linalg.lstsq:
    max_degree = sum(self.degree)
    scale = False

    x = self.e.to_numpy()
    y = self.f.to_numpy()
    z = self.cd.to_numpy()
    # Flatten input
    x = np.asarray(x).ravel()
    y = np.asarray(y).ravel()
    z = np.asarray(z).ravel()

    # Remove masked values
    mask = ~(np.ma.getmask(z) | np.ma.getmask(x) | np.ma.getmask(y))
    x, y, z = x[mask].ravel(), y[mask].ravel(), z[mask].ravel()

    # Scale coordinates to smaller values to avoid numerical problems at larger degrees
    if scale:
        x, y, norm, offset = self._scale()

    coeff = np.zeros((self.degree[0] + 1, self.degree[1] + 1))
    idx = EF_Poly2D_CD_Model._get_coeff_idx(coeff)

    # Calculate elements 1, x, y, x*y, x**2, y**2, ...
    # np.vander will only create powers of 1 variable, it takes 1-D arrays
    A = self.polyvander2d(self.degree)
    # masking: We only want the combinations with maximum order COMBINED power
    if max_degree is not None:
        mask = (idx[:, 0] + idx[:, 1]) <= int(max_degree)
        idx = idx[mask]
        A = A[:, mask]
    # masking: We only want to keep factors that are in the coeff_mask
    mask = np.ones((idx.shape[0],)).astype(bool)
    if self.coeff_mask is not None:
        for i in range(idx.shape[0]):
            mask[i] = (idx[i, 0], idx[i, 1]) in self.coeff_mask
        mask = mask.astype(bool)
        idx = idx[mask]
        A = A[:, mask]
    # add support for regularization
    n_variables = A.shape[1]
    if self.lambd != 0:
        A = np.concatenate([A, np.sqrt(self.lambd) * np.eye(n_variables)])
        z = np.concatenate([z, np.zeros(n_variables)])

    # Do the actual least squares fit
    C, residuals, *_ = lstsq(A, z)

    # Reorder coefficients into numpy compatible 2d array
    for k, (i, j) in enumerate(idx):
        coeff[i, j] = C[k]

    # Reverse the scaling
    if scale:
        coeff = self.polyscale2d(coeff, *norm, copy=False)
        coeff = self.polyshift2d(coeff, *offset, copy=False)

Is there an algorithm that can achieve this? Ideally I'd like to use one of the popular python packages: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn etc

how have you solved it for the case of unbounded y ? please post a minimal example code as text to help people understand what you are trying to do, i'd say look into scipy.optimize.minimize, but no one can help you any better without more context.

Isn't y a known value that the optimizer can't change? So this constraint is either always satisfied or always violated. I think maybe you mean that c1 < X*b < c2.

This answer assumes you mean:

Certain constraints on predictions (i.e. Xb, not the real y and not coefficients).
Model form being y = Xb (i.e. not a GLM or a nonparametric model).

This looks like a constrained optimization problem. One way to solve this is Sequential Least Squares Programming.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# Sample data
# You'll likely need a scaler and/or bias to ensure convergence
# for your actual data if you encounter 'Exit mode 8'.
X = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100, 2))
y = np.dot(X, np.array([3, 4])) + np.random.normal(scale=1, size=100)

# Loss function (MSE):
def objective_function(b):
    y_pred = np.dot(X, b)
    return np.mean((y - y_pred)**2)

result = minimize(
    objective_function,
    # Starting coefs:
    np.array([0, 0]),
    constraints=
    [
        # Lower constraint 0.1: function result must be >= 0
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda b: np.dot(X, b) - 0.1},
        # Upper constraint 6.0:
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda b: 6.0 - np.dot(X, b)},
    ],
    # No restrictions for coefs:
    bounds=((None, None), (None, None)),
    # COBYLA should also work, so should trust-constr,
    # but the latter might need a different notation.
    method='SLSQP',
    options={'disp':True},
)

print("Optimal coefficients:", result.x)
print(f"Pred. range: {np.dot(X, result.x).min():.3f}..{np.dot(X, result.x).max():.3f}")
print(f"Sample range: {y.min():.3f}..{y.max():.3f}")



lambda b: 6.0 - np.dot(X, b) This constraint is linear, and linear constraints are much more efficient than function-defined constraints, because the solver can automatically determine where the constraint is satisfied instead of repeatedly calling the constraint function. 2) If you have no bounds, why supply the bounds argument at all?


minimize() docs state that SLSQP should use the dict format, though in reality, a LinearConstraint does work indeed, at least for the recent scipy versions.
